# A tool to transform simple geometries/shapes to plain text (for use as a code comment)

Tags: geometry, comments

I frequently write code which performs operations on geometries (in 2d and 3d).
To test such code, some input geometries are often hardcoded in unit-tests as arrays of points.
To simplify understanding of test cases it is always nice to have drawing of those geometries as code comments.

Is someone aware of a tool which might help me with generation of such comments?

Thanks in advance,
Dmitry

```
    [TestCase]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        var pnts = new List<Point3d>() {
            new Point3d(30, 80, 0),
            new Point3d(50, 50, 0),
            new Point3d(50, 30, 0),
            new Point3d(30, 0, 0),
            new Point3d(10, 30, 0),
            new Point3d(10, 50, 0),
        };
        // some AAA logic
   }

    /// <summary>
    /// Input geometry:
    ///                /\
    ///               /  \
    ///              /    \
    ///              |    |
    ///              |    |
    ///              \    /
    ///               \  /
    ///           O    \/
    /// </summary>
```

Comment: I am not aware of such a tool, however, it seems like the number of shapes and configurations you frequently need for your unit tests is finite. Given that you already have written many tests, you could maybe extract the templates and sketches to produce a catalog that you can re-use in the future.

Comment: A quick search yielded the following results: [AsciiFlow](http://asciiflow.com/), [Monodraw](https://monodraw.helftone.com/), [ASCII Art Studio](http://www.torchsoft.com/en/aas_information.html)